# How to compare enum values in switch-case?

Tags: c, pointers, enums, switch-statement

Why does the default case fire for the following:

```
    typedef enum {VALUE_ONE, VALUE_TWO} someValue;

    typedef struct {
      someValue value;
    } myStruct;

---main() BELOW---

    myStruct* myPtr = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
    myPtr->value = VALUE_ONE;

    switch (myPtr->value) {
      case VALUE_ONE:
        ...;

      case VALUE_TWO:
        ...;

      default:
        ...;
    }
```

If I use if-statements, the code will work properly. Currently, I would like to use the switch-case to print out value specific phrases.

**UPDATE:** Forgot break statement. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Are you using `break;` at the end of each `case`?

Comment: Above code will work in switch- case also. Note that you need to add a break after every case.

Comment: HAHAHA, that's embarrassing. Forgot break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `break` statement in `switch` case so that when a `break` statement is reached, the switch terminates and the flow of control jumps to the next line following the switch statement.

```
switch (myPtr->value) {
      case VALUE_ONE:
        ...;
        break;

      case VALUE_TWO:
        ...;
       break;

      default:
        ...;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While using the switch case statement, you have to do something like this to get the correct result

```
switch ( <variable> ) {
case 1:
  Code to execute if <variable> == this-value
  break;
case 2:
  Code to execute if <variable> == that-value
  break;
...
default:
  Code to execute if <variable> does not equal the value following any of the cases
  break;
}
```

suppose you missed the break statement of case 2, so whenever the switch-case 2 will be true, it will enter in all the other cases(which comes after case 2) utill the code encounters a break statement.
Break statement is used to come out the case after performing the desired action.
Hope so it's clear.